# React Fetch 404 but Curl and Postman-like calls receive 200

Tags: reactjs, api, post, http-status-code-404

My application always receives a 404 response from my API call but curl and other methods work as expected. So I assume that there is something going on in my React code with the fetch. I have tried not using the header and I still don't get a different response. I also have console logged my body parameters both before and after JSON.stringify and it looks as expected.

Here are some code snippets:

[React code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyr95.png)

[App with console shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4rjH.png)

[Success outside of app with same parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QInHc.png)

[Successful curl with same parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYgTV.png)

Comment: is your URL right?

Comment: Both of your successful calls are using port 5000, while your unsuccessful call is to port 3000. Is that intentional?

Comment: Thanks Jamal. I wasn't thinking and the proxy for the server was configured in the wrong json.package file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem you should put the ip address of the host machine not 127.0.0.1